# how to get a String from a string-array in a jsp and use it in a servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am trying to get a string variable from a jsp file so I can use it in  servlet.
I have got this variable from database and put it in an array list then redirected it to the jsp file and now I need to use it in another action of the same servlet.

```
             `PreparedStatement st4=(PreparedStatement) 
              cn.prepareStatement("select nom_module from module where 
              id_filiere='"+rs3.getInt("id_filiere")+"' and 
              id_semestre='"+rs3.getInt("id_semestre")+"' ");
              rs4=st4.executeQuery();
               while(rs4.next()){

                           String m = rs4.getString("nom_module");
                            list_module.add(m);
                        }
                        session.setAttribute("listmodule", list_module);

          request.getRequestDispatcher("/etudiant.jsp").forward(request, response); `
```

In the jsp file you will see that the variables are in a bar menu , so what I need is to be able to extract the value of the button I clicked on.

```html
<li>
   <div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" style="color:#fff;line-height:60px;margin:0 10px" id="dLabel" 
   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Modules
   <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <c:forEach items="${listmodule }" var="m">
      <li><a href="./PFEaction?action=documentetudiant">${m}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
 </div>
</li>
```

now the ${m} variable is the one I want to get and then use it in the following code :

`if(request.getParameter("action").equals("commentaireetudiant")){

```
            int id1=0 , id2=0;

            String contenu = request.getParameter("contenu");

            PreparedStatement ps4 = (PreparedStatement) 
            cn.prepareStatement("select * from user where username = 
            '"+e.username+"' ");

            ResultSet rs8 = ps4.executeQuery();
            if(rs8.next()){
                id1=rs8.getInt("id_user");
            }

            PreparedStatement ps5 = (PreparedStatement) 
            cn.prepareStatement("select * from module where nom_module = 
            '"+m+"' ");

            ResultSet rs9 = ps5.executeQuery();
            if(rs9.next()){
                id2=rs9.getInt("id_module");
            }

            PreparedStatement ps6 = (PreparedStatement) 
            cn.prepareStatement("insert into commenter (id_user, id_module, 
            contenu) values ('"+id1+"', '"+id2+"', '"+contenu+"') ");
            ps6.executeUpdate();

            request.getRequestDispatcher("/document-
            etudiant.jsp").forward(request, response);
 }`
```

In this servlet code the preparedstatement ps5 is where I use the variable . Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are passing "documentetudiant" as action to the servlet, but you can replace it with the "m" var have servlet get its value as action. Here is the updated JSP:

```html
<li>
   <div class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" style="color:#fff;line-height:60px;margin:0 10px" id="dLabel" 
   data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Modules
   <span class="caret"></span>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <c:forEach items="${listmodule }" var="m">
      <li><a href="./PFEaction?action=<%=m%>">${m}</a></li>
    </c:forEach>
    </ul>
 </div>
</li>
```